# Mocking method used in controller action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, nunit

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int?id)
 {
      MyModel model = new MyModel();
      return View(model);
 }

 [Test]
 public void Can_Open_SomeAction()
 {
     // controller is already set inside `SetUp` unit step.
     ViewResult res = this.controller.SomeAction() as ViewResult;
     var model = result.Model as MyModel;
     Assert.IsNotNull(model);
 }
```

this test passes succ. but when when change controller action to have populate combos like

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int?id)
{
   MyModel model = new MyModel();
   this.PopulatePageCombos(id);
   return View(model);
}
```

I'm getting error on line this.PopulatePageCombos(id);

```
Object reference is not set
```

So, how can I mock this PopulatePageCombos method in unit test?

Update:

```
 public ActionResult SomeAction(int?id)
 {
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    this.PopulatePageCombos(model.Id, 100);
    return View(model);
 }
```

Update 2:

```
PopulatePageCombos (model, countryId, requesterId);
```

where `model` is of type `MyModel`, `countryId` is `int` and `requesterId` is `int`

Comment: what does `this.PopulatePageCombos(id)` do/use? It is dependent on something that does not exist during the test. identify what that is and then you can decide how to test your method under test (MUT)

Comment: @Nkosi, actually it uses two params, I just updated my question. Is it possible to mock this inside nunit SetUp method to avoid using of any external helpers?

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. Look at the body of the `PopulatePageCombos` method. What does the method definition look like. Also your updated post no longer uses the id parameter so it doesn't matter what you pass to it now the result should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper `class PopulatePageCombosHelper` and encapsulate `PopulatePageCombos` method in it. So the `SomeAction` method would look like

```
public PopulatePageCombosHelper populatePageHelper;

public ActionResult SomeAction(int?id)
{
   MyModel model = new MyModel();
   populatePageHelper.PopulatePageCombos(id);
   return View(model);
}
```

So then you can mock `populatePageHelper`

```
[Test]
public void Can_Open_SomeAction()
{
    // controller is already set inside `SetUp` unit step.
    var populatePageHelperMock = new Mock<PopulatePageCombosHelper>();
    controller.populatePageHelper = populatePageHelperMock;
    ViewResult res = this.controller.SomeAction() as ViewResult;
    var model = result.Model as JobCreate;

    //...
    Assert.IsNotNull(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `PopulatePageCombos` method virtual and override it in derived class `ControllerTestable` and test the `ControllerTestable`

```
public class ControllerTestable : Controller
{
    public bool IsCalled = false;
    public override ViewResult SomeAction()
    {
        IsCalled = true;
        return null;
    }
}
```

So in the test instead of creating `Controller controller` you can create `ControllerTestable controller`.

```
[Setup]
public void SetUp () 
{
    var controller = new ControllerTestable();
    //...
}

[Test]
public void Can_Open_SomeAction()
{
    // controller is already set inside `SetUp` unit step.
    ViewResult res = this.controller.SomeAction() as ViewResult;
    var model = result.Model as JobCreate;

    //...
    Assert.IsTrue(controller.IsCalled);
    Assert.IsNotNull(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can partial mock the controller. Having:

```
public virtual void PopulatePageCombos(int? id)
{
    throw new NullReferenceException();
}

public ActionResult SomeAction(int? id)
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();

    this.PopulatePageCombos(id);

    return View(model);
}
```

Then you setup the method PopulatePageCombos to do anything:

```
public class Default1ControllerTests
{
    private Mock<Default1Controller> controllerMock;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        this.controllerMock = new Mock<Default1Controller>() { CallBase = true };

        this.controllerMock.Setup(m => m.PopulatePageCombos(It.IsAny<int?>())).Callback(() => { });
    }

    [Test]
    public void Can_Open_SomeAction()
    {
        // controller is already set inside `SetUp` unit step.
        ViewResult res = this.controllerMock.Object.SomeAction(null) as ViewResult;

        var model = res.Model as MyModel;

        Assert.IsNotNull(model);
    }
}
```

It's important **to declare virtual** the method to mock and specify **CallBase = true** on mock creation. This will call the programmed logic on methods not setup.